"Transverse" subgroups
Given a finitely presented group $G = \langle S \mid R \rangle$ ($S=S^{-1}$) with $2$ subgroups $H$ and $K$. Write $H \pitchfork K \iff \displaystyle \underline{\lim} \limits_{x \in H, d(x,e) \rightarrow +\infty} \frac{d(x,K)}{d(x,e)} \gt 0$, where $d$ is the word metric on $G$ with respect to $S$.
Is it true that $H \pitchfork K \iff K \pitchfork H \iff \# (H \cap K) \lt +\infty$? The answers for both equivalence are affirmative in the extreme cases (where the problem arose) when $G$ is commutative (similar to transverse subspaces in Euclidean space) or free (the limit inferior being $1$), and when one of $H,K$ is finite.
I'm also thankful to see a stronger result that only requires $G$ to be finitely generated or a weaker result that additionally requires $H,K$ to be finitely generated.

The choice of subset $R$ (and the assumption that $R$ is finite) seems to play no role in the definition.

@YCor Yes, $R$ plays no role in the definition, but its finiteness may influence the result.

I'm working in a finitely generated group $G$ with subgroups $H,K$.
The first equivalence $H \pitchfork K \iff K \pitchfork H$ is true in general. Indeed $H \pitchfork K$ fails iff there exists a sequence $(h_n,k_n)$ in $H\times K$ such that $|h_n|\to\infty$, $|k_n|\to\infty$, and $h_n^{-1}k_n=o(|h_n|)$. (In this case $|h_n|/|k_n|\to 1$, so this definition is symmetric in $H$, $K$.)
Indeed if there exists such a sequence, $d(h_n,K)/d(h_n,e)\le d(h_n,k_n)/|h_n|\to 0$, so the lim-inf is zero, and hence $H \pitchfork K$ fails. Conversely if it fails, by definition there exists $(h_n)$ in $H$ such that $|h_n|\to\infty$ and $d(h_n,K)/|h_n|$ tends to zero, so there exists $(k_n)$ in $K$ with $d(h_n,k_n)/|h_n|$ tending to zero, and hence $k_n$ also tends to infinity.

However the last equivalence can fail, even in finitely presented groups, with $H,K$ infinite cyclic. A simple example is in $G=\mathrm{Hei}\times\mathbf{Z}$, where $\mathrm{Hei}$ is the integral Heisenberg group. Let $z$ be a generator of the center in $\mathrm{Hei}$, and $s$ a generator of $\mathbf{Z}$ (using multiplicative law). Write $H=\langle s\rangle$ and $K=\langle sz\rangle$; both are central, infinite cyclic subgroups, and $H\cap K=\{1\}$. Write $h_n=s^n$ and $k_n=(sz)^n=s^nz^n$. Then $h_n^{-1}k_n=z^n$, so $|h_n|$, $|k_n|$ grow linearly while $|h_n^{-1}k_n|$ grows in $\sqrt{n}$, so $H \pitchfork K$ fails.
